# Material UI datagrid with nested data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, material-ui, react-data-grid

How do I render nested JSON data on react material UI data grid. In the sandbox attached I want to show the phone numbers of the users from the json on the data grid-[Nested JSON Data Grid](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-2sc7v)

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please review [ask] and provide a [mcve] when asking a question.

Comment: Why not flatten your json object?

Comment: Hi I have added the sandbox url in the question @admcfajn

Comment: @JaniceZhong, this is just a sample of what I am trying to achieve...the real data is more complex

Comment: Yes @LearnerForever but it would be easier for everyone to collaborate on if you create a snippet here :)

Comment: @admcfajn here's the snippet https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-2sc7v

Comment: You could just re-arrange your json data structure, here's an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-3xcjn

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To solve the problem, let's see `params` object passed in `valueGetter` function. Log that and you will find a `row` object under it. Instead of using `params.getValue()`, you should access the `row` object. It seems that `params.getValue()` can only be used on one-level JSON object. Here is the code snippet to output `phone` field.

```
  {
    field: "phone",
    headerName: "Phone",
    width: 160,
    valueGetter: (params) => {
      console.log({ params });
      let result = [];
      if (params.row.phone) {
        if (params.row.phone.home) {
          result.push("home: " + params.row.phone.home);
        }
        if (params.row.phone.office) {
          result.push("office: " + params.row.phone.office);
        }
      } else {
        result = ["Unknown"];
      }
      return result.join(", ");
    }
  }
```

**Update**

To have more flexibility on checking if every key under a object exists, I have created a helper method:

```
const checkKeysUnderObject = (obj, result) => {
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (key) { // push the value to the result array only if key exists
      result.push(key + ": " + obj[key]);
    }
  }
};
```

usage of the helper method:

```
if (params.row.phone) {
  checkKeysUnderObject(params.row.phone, result);
}else{
  result = ["Unknown"];
}
```

I have also updated the codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-gkhew?file=/demo.js).

Comment: The sandbox is returning errors...
No row with id #firstName found

Comment: I worked around the error using this:
valueGetter: params => `${params?.params?.row?.firstName || ""} ${params?.params?.row?.lastName || ""}`

Comment: Also, are we saying that sorting is not an option for nested object responses?  I'm currently on the fence as to this approach or passing API response through a method to flatten it so `,phone:{home:"11", office:"22" }` would become `,phone_home:"11", phone_office:"22"`

Answer (score 28):

I use this in my project :

```
{ 
    field: 'idMaintenancePlan',
    headerName: 'Plan de maintenance', 
    sortable: false, width: 200, 
    valueGetter: (params) => params.row?.maintenancePlan?.name 
}
```

Comment: In new v5 version - this will not work. Instead use valueGetter.

Comment: This works fine in v5 like valueGetter

Comment: Take into account that the value that we get from `valueFormatter` is not used for filtering and sorting so in the majority of cases using `valueGetter` will be a better solution.

From [MUI Data-grid documentation](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-definition/#value-formatter):
The value generated is only used for rendering purposes. Filtering and sorting do not rely on the formatted value. Use the valueParser to support filtering.

Comment: For current version, it's like following:
`valueGetter: (params) => params.row?.jobType?.name`

Answer (score 8):

this works fine for me

```
{ field: 'parserInfo', headerName: 'Parser Title', valueFormatter: ({ value }) => value.title }
```

Answer (score 6):

this works fine also

```html
{
     field: "family",
     headerName: "Family",
     width: 150,
     renderCell: (params) => {
       return <div className="rowitem">{params.row.family.name}</div>;
     },
},
```

Comment: suggestion : you can use code fences instead of snippets since the snippet feature here is not necessary, also add a language identifier to highlight the code based on the language and make it more readable

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
const columns = [
    { 
        field: "post", 
        headerName: "TITLE", 
        valueFormatter: (post: any) => post.value.title
    }
]
```

In my case `post` is a property of the `tutorial` entity.

```
<DataGrid
    rows={tutorials}
    columns={columns}
    slots={{
        toolbar: GridToolbar,
    }}
/>
```

The `Tutorial` entity

```
export interface Tutorial {
    id: number;

    ...

    post: Post;
}
```

... and the `Post` entity.

```
export interface Post {
    id: number;
    title: string;

    ...
}
```